# Use Spring Data mongodb to store XMLBeans as BSON objects

Tags: mongodb-java, xmlbeans, spring-data-mongodb

I am looking into using Spring Data mongodb and so far I like what I see. However, when I try to store more complicated objects, for example one created using APache XMLBeans, I get a StackOverFlowError. I think this is due to the cyclic nature of object refrences in the XMlBean. Does anyone have any suggestions as to a general way to store an XmlBean in mongodb as a BSON object that will allow for searching?

The solution does not need to use Spring.

Comment: did you take help of repository or mongo template to upsert data into mongoDB , for me XML beans are nothing less than Pojo. one thing you can do is create your own POJO extending xmlbean class and try to save it using repository .